# I'm a new CDS/Dataverse user and am wondering why there are so many columns in new tables?

Tags: common-data-service, power-platform

I'm new to CDS/Dataverse, coming from the SQL Server world.  I created a new Dataverse table and there are over a dozen columns in my "new" table (e.g. "status", "version number"). Apparently these are added automatically. Why is this?

Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to view a grid of data (like I can with SQL Server) for quick review/modification of the data. Is there a way to view data visually like this?

Any tips for a new user, coming from SQL Server, would be appreciated.  Thanks.

---

Edit: clarified the main question with examples (column names). (thanks David)

Comment: Welcome! I would suggest only asking one question, not multiple separate questions. That said: It's unclear what you mean by "extra columns." When editing your question, you should clarify what you did, and perhaps more details of what you saw and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to CDS/Dataverse, so the following is a limited understanding from what I have explored so far.

The idea behind Dataverse is that it gives you a pre-built schema that follows best-practice for you build off of, so that you spend less time worrying about building a comprehensive data schema, creating tables, and how to relate them all together, and more time building applications in Power Apps.

For example, amongst the several dozen tables it generates from the get-go is **Account** and **Contact**. The former is for organisational entities and the latter is for single-person entities. You can go straight into adding your user records in one of these tables and take advantage of bits of Power Apps functionality already hooked up to these tables. You do not have to spend time thinking up column names, creating the table, making sure it hooks up to all the other Dataverse tables, testing whether the Power Apps functionality works with it correctly etc.

It is much the same story with the automatically generated columns for new tables: they are all there to maintain a best-practice schema and functionality for Power Apps. For example, the extra columns give you good auditing with the data you add, including when a row was created, modified, who created the row etc. The important thing is to start from what you want to build, and not get too caught up in the extra tables/columns. After a bit of research, you'll probably find you can utilise some more tables/columns in your design.

Viewing and adding data is very tedious -- it seems to take 5 clicks and several seconds to load the bit of data you want, which is eons in comparison to doing it in SQL Server. I believe it is how it is due to Microsoft's attempt to make it "user friendly".

Anyhow, the standard way to view data, starting from the main Power Apps view is:

1. From the right-hand side pane, click Data
2. Click Tables
3. From the list of tables, click your table
4. Along the top row, click Data

There is an alternative method that allows you to view the Dataverse tables in SSMS – see link below:

https://www.strategy365.co.uk/using-sql-to-query-the-common-data-service/

To import data in bulk:

1. Click on Data from the top drop-down menu > Get data.

Importing data from Excel is free. To import from other sources, including SQL Server, I believe is a paid service (although I think you may be able to do this on the free Community Plan).